# Not able to load more batch size in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to load (128,224,224,3) batch_data in tensorflow. I am getting Memory Error but if I load the same in Theano it is working fine. Why is this happening in tensorflow alone. Any idea to change the memory parameter in tensorflow ?

Comment: Are you running on a GPU? If so, what GPU?

Comment: yes, Quadro K4000,Tesla K40c,Tesla K40c

Comment: Theano has some optimizations which aren't in TensorFlow. For instance, Theano has cwise fusion, so if you have consecutive cwise ops, you'll use more memory in TensorFlow